# How to calculate next months dates?

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate next months 5 date.

For e.g consider todays `10-jan-2017` date then next date should be between next months 5th. i.e before `05-feb-2017`

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking for. Please elaborate more...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `momentjs` to handle date. http://momentjs.com/docs/

```
var today = moment();
var nextDate = today.add(1, 'months').startOf('month').add(5, 'days');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Date#setMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) method with both month and day arguments.

```js
// get current date
var date = new Date();

// add month and update day
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1, 5);
// or set day by date.setDate(5);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: (date.getMonth() + 1) %12

Comment: and year = date.getYear() + (date.getMonth() + 1) / 12

Comment: @UG_ that would result `05-dec-2017` => `05-jan-2017` ..... what it require is `05-jan-2018`

Comment: @UG_ :  ___If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setMonth() attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for monthValue, the year will be incremented by 1, and 3 will be used for month.___ Taken from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth#Description

Comment: Consider both the comments. But anyways it internally takes care of it.